# Where to define the parameters in powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I have downloaded this powershell script which copies Power BI report contents into a new file, however I don't understand where I should input the parameter values for SourceReportId, SourceWorkspaceId, TargetReportId, TargetWorkspaceId, etc.

Script is available here also: https://github.com/JamesDBartlett3/PowerBits/blob/main/PowerShell/Copy-PowerBIReportContentToBlankPBIXFile.ps1

```
`<#
  .SYNOPSIS
    Function: Copy-PowerBIReportContentToBlankPBIXFile
    Author: @JamesDBartlett3 (James D. Bartlett III)

  .DESCRIPTION
    - This script will copy the contents of a published Power BI 
      report into a new report published from a blank PBIX 
    - This solves the problem where a Power BI report originally 
      created in the web browser cannot be downloaded from the 
      Power BI service as a PBIX file.

  .PARAMETER SourceReportId 
    The ID of the report to copy from

  .PARAMETER SourceWorkspaceId
    The ID of the workspace to copy from

  .PARAMETER TargetReportId
    The ID of the report to copy to

  .PARAMETER TargetWorkspaceId
    The ID of the workspace to copy to

  .PARAMETER BlankPbix 
    Local path (or URL) to a blank PBIX file to upload and copy the source report's contents into

  .PARAMETER OutFile 
    Local path to save the new PBIX file to

  .EXAMPLE
    Copy-PowerBIReportContentToBlankPBIXFile -SourceReportId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012" -SourceWorkspaceId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012" -TargetReportId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012" -TargetWorkspaceId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"

  .NOTES
    This function does NOT require Azure AD app registration, 
    service principal creation, or any other special setup.
    The only requirements are:
      - The user must be able to run PowerShell (and install the
        MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt module, if it's not already installed).
      - The user must be allowed to download report PBIX files
        (see: "Download reports" setting in the Power BI Admin Portal).
      - The user must have "Contributor" or higher permissions 
        on the source and target workspace(s).
    
    TODO
      - Testing
      - Add usage, help, and examples.
      - Rename the function to something more accurate to its current capabilities.
  
    ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
      This PS function was inspired by a blog article written by 
      one of the top minds in the Power BI space, Mathias Thierbach.
      And if you're not already using his pbi-tools for Power BI
      version control, you should check it out: https://pbi.tools
#>

Function Copy-PowerBIReportContentToBlankPBIXFile {
  
  #Requires -PSEdition Core
  #Requires -Modules MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
  
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$SourceReportId,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$SourceWorkspaceId,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string]$TargetReportId,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string]$TargetWorkspaceId = $SourceWorkspaceId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string]$BlankPbix,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string]$OutFile
  )
  
  $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
  
  [string]$blankPbixTempFile = Join-Path -LiteralPath $env:TEMP -ChildPath "blank.pbix"
  [array]$validPbixContents = @("Layout", "Metadata")
  
  [bool]$blankPbixIsUrl = $BlankPbix.StartsWith("http")
  [bool]$localFileExists = Test-Path $BlankPbix
  [bool]$remoteFileIsValid = $false
  [bool]$localFileIsValid = $false
  [bool]$defaultFileIsValid = $false
  
  Function FileIsBlankPbix($file) {
    $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($file)
    $fileIsPbix = @($validPbixContents | Where-Object {$zip.Entries.Name -Contains $_}).Count -gt 0
    $fileIsBlank = (Get-Item $file).length / 1KB -lt 20
    $zip.Dispose()
    if($fileIsPbix -and $fileIsBlank) {
      Write-Debug "$file is a valid blank pbix file."
      return $true
    }
    else {
      Write-Error "$file is NOT a valid blank pbix file."
      return $false
    }
  }
  
  # If user did not specify a target report ID, use a blank PBIX file
  if(!$TargetReportId) {

    # If user specified a URL to a file, download and validate it as a blank PBIX file
    if ($blankPbixIsUrl){
      Write-Debug "Downloading file: $BlankPbix..."
      Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $BlankPbix -OutFile $blankPbixTempFile
      Write-Debug "Validating downloaded file..."
      $remoteFileIsValid = FileIsBlankPbix($blankPbixTempFile)
    }
    
    # If user specified a local path to a file, validate it as a blank PBIX file
    elseif ($localFileExists) {
      Write-Debug "Validating user-supplied file: $BlankPbix..."
      $localFileIsValid = FileIsBlankPbix($BlankPbix)
    }
    
    # If user didn't specify a blank PBIX file, check for a valid blank PBIX in the temp location
    elseif (Test-Path $blankPbixTempFile) {
      Write-Debug "Validating pbix file found in temp location: $blankPbixTempFile..."
      $defaultFileIsValid = FileIsBlankPbix($blankPbixTempFile)
    }
    
    # If user did not specify a blank PBIX file, and a valid blank PBIX is not in the temp location,
    # download one from GitHub and check if it's valid and blank
    else {
      Write-Debug "Downloading a blank pbix file from GitHub to $blankPbixTempFile..."
      $BlankPbixUri = "https://github.com/JamesDBartlett3/PowerBits/raw/main/Misc/blank.pbix"
      Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $BlankPbixUri -OutFile $blankPbixTempFile
      $defaultFileIsValid = FileIsBlankPbix($blankPbixTempFile)
    }
    
    # If we downloaded a valid blank PBIX file, use it.
    if ($remoteFileIsValid -or $defaultFileIsValid) {
      $BlankPbix = $blankPbixTempFile
    }
    
    # If a valid blank PBIX file could not be obtained by any of the above methods, throw an error.
    if (!$TargetReportId -and !$localFileIsValid -and !$remoteFileIsValid -and !$defaultFileIsValid) {
      Write-Error "No targetReportId specified & no valid blank PBIX file found. Please specify one or the other."
      return
    }
    
    [bool]$pbixIsValid = ($localFileIsValid -or $remoteFileIsValid -or $defaultFileIsValid)
    
  }
  
  try {
    $headers = Get-PowerBIAccessToken
  }
  
  catch {
    Write-Output "Power BI Access Token required. Launching authentication dialog..."
    Start-Sleep -s 1
    Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
    $headers = Get-PowerBIAccessToken
  }
  
  finally {
    Write-Debug "Target Report ID is null: $(!$TargetReportId)"
    $pbiApiBaseUri = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg"
    
    # If a valid blank PBIX was found, publish it to the target workspace
    if ($pbixIsValid) {
      Write-Debug "Publishing $BlankPbix to target workspace..."
      $publishResponse = New-PowerBIReport -Path $BlankPbix -WorkspaceId $TargetWorkspaceId -ConflictAction CreateOrOverwrite
      Write-Debug "Response: $publishResponse"
      $TargetReportId = $publishResponse.Id
    }
    
    # Assemble the UpdateReportContent API URI and request body
    $updateReportContentEndpoint = "$pbiApiBaseUri/groups/$TargetWorkspaceId/reports/$TargetReportId/UpdateReportContent"
    $body = @"
      {
        "sourceReport": {
          "sourceReportId": "$SourceReportId",
          "sourceWorkspaceId": "$SourceWorkspaceId"
        },
        "sourceType": "ExistingReport"
      }
"@
    # Update the target report with the source report's content
    $headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateReportContentEndpoint -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $body
    
    # If user did not specify an output file, use the source report's name
    $sourceReportName = (Get-PowerBIReport -Id $SourceReportId -WorkspaceId $SourceWorkspaceId).Name
    $OutFile = $OutFile ?? "$($sourceReportName)_Clone.pbix"
    
    # Export the target report to a PBIX file
    Export-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId $TargetWorkspaceId -Id $response.id -OutFile $OutFile
    
    # Assemble the Datasets API URI
    $datasetsEndpoint = "$pbiApiBaseUri/groups/$TargetWorkspaceId/datasets"
    
    
    
  }
  
}`
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I do not understand the problem. There is even an example in the Help section.

Comment: The example in the help section (in case you've overlooked it): `Copy-PowerBIReportContentToBlankPBIXFile -SourceReportId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012" -SourceWorkspaceId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012" -TargetReportId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012" -TargetWorkspaceId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have saved the script in a file "Copy-PowerBIReportContentToBlankPBIXFile.ps1", [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.3#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) the file to make its function available (if you would call the script without dot-sourcing it, the function would be scoped to the script and not visible to the outside):

```sh
# Assumes the script is located in the current directory
. .\Copy-PowerBIReportContentToBlankPBIXFile.ps1
```

Now you can call the function from the script like this to get a list of parameters:

```sh
Copy-PowerBIReportContentToBlankPBIXFile -?
```

Don't get confused, the function just coincidentally has the same name as the script, in principle it could be named different.

The help section in the comments gives a full example of how to call the function:

```sh
Copy-PowerBIReportContentToBlankPBIXFile -SourceReportId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012" -SourceWorkspaceId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012" -TargetReportId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012" -TargetWorkspaceId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"
```

If you look at the parameter definitions, only `-SourceReportId` and `-SourceWorkspaceId` are mandatory (`Mandatory = $true`), so the other parameters could be omitted if this makes sense for your use case.

```sh
Copy-PowerBIReportContentToBlankPBIXFile -SourceReportId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012" -SourceWorkspaceId "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"
```